# Poisson Regression Model

Tags: poisson-regression, irls

Kindly explain me how to estimate poisson regression model using iterative weighted least square method. I know it can be easily estimated in any software like Stata, SAS, SPSS etc but I want to estimate it manually.  I am unable to understand the weight matrix (W) in the following iterative estimation equation:
$$   b =(X^\mathrm{T}WX)^{-1}X^\mathrm{T}Wz   $$

Comment: Note $X^\mathrm{T}$ means the transpose of the matrix $X$, but $XT$ means the product of matrices $X$ & $T$. (I've fixed it.) Also, though the equation's fairly standard, it would be helpful to define the symbols.

Comment: Look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a